# C++ Stacks Pop General Theory

Tags: c++, stack

I am confused on how the code below can be sent a variable and then change that variable to the value at the top of the stack without "returning" a value.  So if 1 was at the top I could do stack.pop(variable) and then variable would equal 1.

```
void DynIntStack::pop(int &num)
{
   StackNode *temp; // Temporary pointer

   // First make sure the stack isn't empty.
   if (isEmpty())
   {
      cout << "The stack is empty.\n";
   }
   else  // pop value off top of stack
   {
      num = top->value;
      temp = top->next;
      delete top;
      top = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand C++ references at all?

Comment: Yes but maybe I am not understanding it correctly?

Comment: You need to look at pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value...

Comment: @geekosaur: That comment alone is really useless. You should *at least* include a hint about the topic to look at or even better, link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Wikipedia explains it quite well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference#Call_by_reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parameter passed *by reference*.

You can think of it as passing the actual parameter, not just the value. Any modification done to the parameter is reflected to the original variable just because they are the same variable.

Actually the parameter is a reference (pointer) to the memory address of the real value.

Comment: Ahhh I understand now.  So we are referencing the memory address and not the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function that takes a reference, such as

```
void setNum(int &num) {
  num = 4;
}

main(...) {
  int myNum = 2;
  setNum(myNum);
  cout << myNum << endl;
}
```

you're telling the compiler to pass the argument's *address*, rather than its value.  When you assign a value to the reference, it changes the memory at that address.  Then, when the function returns, the original variable still points at the same address, so it assumes the new value.

On the other hand, when you declare a function that takes a *value*, such as

```
void leaveNumUnchanged(int num) {
  num++;
  cout << "The new value is " << num << endl;
}
```

the function makes its own private copy of the argument, and any manipulations affect only the copy.